# Match 4 cells and copy a row

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with random numbers. On my userform I have 4 textboxes for numbers.

Once the program finds the row that meets the criteria (all numbers from the textboxes are present in the row) it should copy that row to the sheet2.

I have no idea how to do that.

```
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim strFirst As String
Dim Height As String
Dim Width As String
Dim MountB As String
Dim MountC As String

Height = TextBox1.Value
Width = TextBox2.Value
MountB = TextBox3.Value
MountC = TextBox4.Value

If Trim(TextBox1.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Or Trim(TextBox2.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Or Trim(TextBox3.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString _
    Or Trim(TextBox4.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then

MsgBox "Enter the missing value(s)"

Else

Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(Height, Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlWhole)


If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    strFirst = rngFound.Address
    Do
        If LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "C").Text) = LCase(Width) And LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text) = LCase(MountB) And LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "E").Text) = LCase(MountC) Then
            'Found a match
           Range(rngFound.Row & Chr(10)).Copy _
           Destination:=Worksheets("data").b

            MsgBox "Found a match at: " & rngFound.Row & Chr(10) & _
                   "BLOCK TYPE: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "A").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "BLOCK LENGHT [L] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "F").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "SCREW SIZE [Mxl]: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "G").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "RAIL WIDTH [Wr] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "H").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "COUNTERBORE DIAM [D] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "I").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "COUNTERBORE DEPTH [h] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "J").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "THRU HOLE DIAM [d] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "K").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "RAIL PITCH [P] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "L").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "E DIMENSION [E] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "M").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "BASIC DYNAMIC LOAD [C] kN: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "N").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "BASIC STATIC LOAD [C0] kN: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "O").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "STATIC MOMENT [MR] kNm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "P").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "STATIC MOMENT [MP] kNm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "Q").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "STATIC MOMENT [MY] kNm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "R").Text


        End If


        Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(Height, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)


    Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst

Else
        MsgBox "No CROSS"

End If
End If



 Set rngFound = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: Are you typically expecting to find more than a single 4 cell match or is the data organized so that only one match would ever be found?

Comment: Is there a particular issue or problem you're having? This seems to be more a statement of fact than a question.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer.

There is more than just one match. It should find and copy every row  he finds.

Comment: @FreeMan  - I edited out some excess narrative; perhaps at least one sentence too much. I've re-edited to include something.

Comment: @Fred - Could you clarify the source and destination of the copy? The example in the code sample makes no sense.

Comment: @Fred - can it be reasonably assumed that you have data labels in row 1 of each of the columns of data?

Comment: @Jeeped - The source is on the sheet1 and the destination is data (I renamed the sheet2)

Comment: @Jeeped - Correct, my first row has Model H W B C L Mxl Wr D h d P E C C0 MR MP MY

Comment: @fred - no ... your source has a linefeed appended to the row and the destination is something called *b*.

Comment: @Jeeped - I just tried this code:

        Range(rngFound.Row & Chr(10)).Copy _
           Destination:=Worksheets("data").b
but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Fred - RIGHT! That makes NO sense. I cannot even guess what you mean by it. Please adequately describe what you want to copy and where you want to put it.

Comment: @Jeeped - I was trying to figure out how to copy the row but that code is not good. I just forgot to delete it when I posted the code. Sorry

Comment: @Jeeped - I have 4 textboxes on the userform. Textbox1 looks for the numbers in column B, textbox2 in C, textbox3 in D and textbox4 in E. I have random numbers on the sheet1 (B2:R100). If there is a row that has the textbox1,2,3,4 order he sends me the message with the row number and lists all the numbers in that row. All that I have in msgbox. Now I want to copy every row that contains the 4 numbers from sheet1 to sheet2

Answer (score 0):

A four column filter would collect all of the four column matches at once. A copy of the filtered results will only copy the visible rows.

```
Sub match_4_and_copy()
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim sHeight As String
    Dim sWidth As String
    Dim sMountB As String
    Dim sMountC As String
    Dim rw As Long

    sHeight = TextBox1.Value
    sWidth = TextBox2.Value
    sMountB = TextBox3.Value
    sMountC = TextBox4.Value

    With ActiveSheet   '<-define this worksheet properly!
        If Not CBool(Len(Trim(TextBox1.Value))) Or _
           Not CBool(Len(Trim(TextBox2.Value))) Or _
           Not CBool(Len(Trim(TextBox3.Value))) Or _
           Not CBool(Len(Trim(TextBox4.Value))) Then

            MsgBox "Enter the missing value(s)"

        ElseIf CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns("B"), sHeight, _
                                          .Columns("C"), sWidth, _
                                          .Columns("D"), sMountB, _
                                          .Columns("E"), sMountC)) Then
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=sHeight
                .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=sWidth
                .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=sMountB
                .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=sMountC
                With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                    .Cells.Copy _
                       Destination:=Worksheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End With
                .AutoFilter
            End With

            With Worksheets("data")
                For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                    'put your big mssg box here based on rw
                Next rw
            End With
        Else

            MsgBox "No CROSS"

        End If
    End With
            'MsgBox "Found a match at: " & rngFound.Row & Chr(10) & _
                   "BLOCK TYPE: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "A").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "BLOCK LENGHT [L] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "F").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "SCREW SIZE [Mxl]: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "G").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "RAIL WIDTH [Wr] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "H").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "COUNTERBORE DIAM [D] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "I").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "COUNTERBORE DEPTH [h] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "J").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "THRU HOLE DIAM [d] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "K").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "RAIL PITCH [P] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "L").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "E DIMENSION [E] mm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "M").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "BASIC DYNAMIC LOAD [C] kN: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "N").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "BASIC STATIC LOAD [C0] kN: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "O").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "STATIC MOMENT [MR] kNm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "P").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "STATIC MOMENT [MP] kNm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "Q").Text & Chr(10) & _
                   "STATIC MOMENT [MY] kNm: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "R").Text

End Sub
```

I will leave it to you to properly define the copy and destination ranges. The `MsgBox` is commented but you should be able to put it into the For/Next loop where I reserved space. The loop goes through each of the copied rows based on *rw*.

Note that *Height* and *Width* are reserved words in VBA. I've renamed these as it is never a good idea to declare your variables with the same names as reserved words.

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. Remember that the msgbox will refer to `.Cells(rw, "A").Text` and not `Cells(rngFound.Row, "A").Text`. The prefixing period tells the msgbox that the cells belong to the worksheet named in the With/End With.

Comment: Thanks again. Is seems that the "No Cross" msgbox is working now too :)